# Issue with simple Google Scripts and Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Update 2: It was a permissions issue.** I guess I have to duplicate all my scripts for each spreadsheet? Also I'm updating my code now that I've fixed it.

Update: my code is wrong (I need to drop the second for loop I think) but my question is why the script isn't running on my sheets.

I'm trying to write data to columns in a spreadsheet. Maybe I'm just having permissions issues?

This is my first time using Google scripts and I'm not familiar with JavaScript either. I have a spreadsheet with a lot of data and I successfully removed duplicates as defined by comparing the first two columns--no bugs, no issues, ran successfully first try. Now I'm trying to fill in data on two new, empty columns.

If column 2 is in the format "foo - bar", I want column 3 to be "foo" and col 4 "bar". So I wrote this script:

```
function parseTypes() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var str = row[2];
    var strSplit = str.split(" - ");
    row[3] = strSplit[0];
    if (strSplit[1] == "" || strSplit[1] == null || row[4] == undefined) {
      row[4] = "";
    } else {
      row[4] = strSplit[1];
    }
    newData.push(row);
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

I debugged in and the string array strSplit is accurately being set to "foo,bar". My issue is that it's not actually writing the data to my spreadsheet. I don't know if it's my code or if I'm just running the script wrong because I barely know what I'm doing.

Comment: About the permissions issues, when you show the situation that you are using your script, it will help users to think of solution. And if you want to split the values of column 2, please reduce 1 from the respective indexes of ``row[index]`` and ``newData[j][index]``. Because although the index of array starts 0, the range starts 1.

Comment: @Tanaike I fixed my code. It now does everything correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript use 0 based indexes but SpreadsheetApp use 1 based indexes. This means that row[2] returns the value of column C not column B.

Comment: That wasn't the issue. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to copy the script. The only thing you need to change is not using the SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet, but you have to use the SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://blalaallla').getSheetByName('blalala') method. This way you don't have to copy it. Hope this helps.